# I already get the Bing Oauth token but can't access user data using that token

Tags: bing-api

How bing oauth connect?

I make bing oauth connection done and get the token from bing.How I get User data from bing using oauth_token.

Answer (score 0):

Download the PHP API V9, and in their examples swap 
$username and $password for $AuthenticationToken.

Then add '$Authentication' to the constructor line where it says null.

They have not updated their docs online and it is not very clear....

Make sure you have a token that lasts....